# Outlook body background no-repeat

Tags: css, outlook, background-image

I am sending an Email in HTML format geared toward outlook 2007/2010. I applied a background image to body tag but it does not work. Code as below:

```
<body 
style="background-image: url('http://example.com/bg.jpg'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:top center;">
```

However if I change the "no-repeat" to "repeat-y no-repeat", it shows the background image but it repeats.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Width Backgrounds on Outlook '07/'10/'13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here you don't want the background image to repeat?

Maybe you want to have a single background image for the header and then a specific background colour behind the main content area?

In this case, assuming it's not possible to have a non-repeating bg image (I'm not sure to be honest), I'd repeat-y the image and have a container below the header, the same width as your background image, with the appropriate bg colour set so it obscures the repeated bg image.

It's also worth adding the bg image to the first table container as well so that if anyone reads the message in a webmail client they'll still see the background image (many webmail clients strip away the head and body tags).

I haven't tested this but here's roughly what I'm thinking:

```
<body style="
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-image:url(http:/example.com/720pxx200px_bg_image.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y no-repeat;
background-position:center top;">

<table style="
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
background-image:url(http:/example.com/720pxx200px_bg_image.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y no-repeat;
background-position:center top;">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table style="
            border-collapse:collapse;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            width:720px;
            height:200px;">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>Header Content Goes Here</h1></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="
            border-collapse:collapse;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            width:720px;
            background-color:#fff;">
            <tr>
                <td><p>Body Content Goes Here</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Choose one style.  repeat-y implies that it doesn't repeat in the x direction.

Comment: If I use no-repeat, it doesn't show up at all in outlook.
That is the issue.

Comment: And if you use just repeat-y?  That's the direction you want it to repeat, correct?

Answer (score -1):

You can hack it with a very wide image, that is positioned in the horizontal center.
It repeats both ways (default).

This should allow you to get the visual effect you are after