# Full Width Backgrounds on Outlook '07/'10/'13

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I've been using campaign monitor's http://backgrounds.cm/ code for single fixed height/width `<td>`s which works great across all desktop clients, but we're moving to full width emails and I can't get the full width option to display correctly in any mso version of outlook. Namely, this happens:

[image: litmustest]

I've followed their directions and kept their code as the first child of `body`, but the background extends into where outlook's margins should be.. I'm trying to find a way in outlook to do separate full width background rows.

Comment: Can you use images instead of background images?

Comment: even if i did, i'd have to use VML's `mso-width-percent` css and that's what's causing the issue with the background.

Answer (score 9):

### Full width table cell background images

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
    <head>
    <style>
    v:* { behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <table width="100%" height="20">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#dddddd" style="background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/500/300');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" background="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" width="100%" height="300">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;height:300px;">
                        <v:fill type="frame" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" color="#ffffff" />
                    </v:rect>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#33cc99">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"><tr><td height="5"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffff99" style="background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/500/300');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" background="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" width="100%" height="300">
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;height:300px;">
                            <v:fill type="frame" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" color="#ffffff" />
                        </v:rect>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

- Tested in Outlook 2010 thru Windows 7 VMWare on OSX 10.9.2

[image]

---

### Tiled full width table cell background images

```
    <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
        <head>
            <style>
                v:* { behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>

        <center>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#dddddd" style="background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/500/300');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" background="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" width="100%" height="300">
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;height:300px;">
                            <v:fill type="tile" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" color="#ffffff" />
                        </v:rect>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </center>

        </body>
    </html>
```

- Tested in Outlook 2010 thru Windows 7 VMWare on OSX 10.9.2

[image]

---

### Specified width table cell background images

Here is an example, two rows, the first row has 3 columns with 3 separate background images, the second row spans all the way across as one background image.

```
    <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 300px; height: 80px; background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/300/80');">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 80px; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0; z-index: 1;' src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/80" />
                <v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 80px; top: -5; left: -10; border: 0; z-index: 2;'>
                <div>
            <![endif]-->
                <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="80" align="center" valign="top" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:20px;">
                            <span>Text</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </div>
                </v:shape>
            <![endif]-->
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 80px; background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/100/80');">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 80px; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0; z-index: 1;' src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/80" />
                <v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 80px; top: -5; left: -10; border: 0; z-index: 2;'>
                <div>
            <![endif]-->
                <table width="80" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="80" align="center" valign="top">
                            <span>Text</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </div>
                </v:shape>
            <![endif]-->
            </td>
            <td style="width: 200px; height: 80px; background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/100');">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 80px; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0; z-index: 1;' src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/100" />
                <v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 80px; top: -5; left: -10; border: 0; z-index: 2;'>
                <div>
            <![endif]-->
                <table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="80" align="center" valign="top" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:20px;">
                            <span>Text</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </div>
                </v:shape>
            <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 600px; height: 150px; background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/600/150');">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 150px; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0; z-index: 1;' src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/150" />
                <v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 150px; top: -5; left: -10; border: 0; z-index: 2;'>
                <div>
            <![endif]-->
                <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="150" align="center" valign="top" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:20px;">
                            <span>Text</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </div>
                </v:shape>
            <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

- Tested in Outlook 2010 thru Windows 7 VMWare on OSX 10.9.2

[image]

Comment: Took a while but I figured it out, updated my answer for you.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort but this is still fixed width (600px). Full width is 100%.

Comment: EmailOnAcid's solution is actually worse than Campaign Monitor's. It doesn't use `inset`, and the background is shifted to the right.

Comment: Please review my answer again, I think I've finally got it.  :)  After about 100 test emails.

Comment: Hate to cause more frustration but the same bleed-error I had on mine is still there on yours. try putting a regular 100% table underneath it with a bgcolor and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: not sure what you mean, because I just stacked 3 tables on top of each other. image on top, 20px tall empty table with a background-color, and another image on the bottom for the heck of it and it works great, results adjusted above. send your mock and i'll make it work.

Comment: Sorry about that, still testing. I'll let you know in a little bit but it looks like it's coming together!

Comment: Let me know if your still having trouble.  I got pretty excited when I figured this out.

Comment: nope, i was right. It looked good because of the cellpadding / spacing, but when i took them out, same issue. The bottom table is a regular one with `border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;"` litmus.com/pub/628657c/screenshots

Comment: The cellpadding is used to set the height of the middle table, it's just cleaner than using height=  I think that at this point, you've gotta give and take a little bit, if you want it to work you can't expect it to be quite as simple as a drop in solution, your undoubtedly going to have to restructure the tables around it slightly.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! Campaign Monitor's Bulletproof Backgrounds failed me for the first time by not correctly aligning the image in Outlook.  The "Specified width table cell background images" section kept the images from shifting.

Comment: using `mso-width-percent:1000` on `v-rec` actually makes the email larger then the outlook screen. You can see that there is a vertical scrollbar on your kitten image. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this fluid template with VML background built in:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a {padding:0;}
    body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Hotmail */
    a:active, a:visited, a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] { text-decoration: none; color: #005288 !important; pointer-events: auto; cursor: default;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { .maxW { width:600px !important; } }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<div style="background-color:#7bceeb;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png" color="#7bceeb"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" background="http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png">
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td valign="top">
<![endif]-->
<table width="100%" class="maxW" style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" align="center">


<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: auto;">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left" valign="top" height="600" style="padding:30px;">
      Content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


</td></tr></table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
</td></tr></table>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Ah well that works (it's full width), but isn't quite what I was going for. I re worded my question. I was going for a full width row, not a tiled background across the whole email. This still goes past outlook's margins and repeats all the way to the bottom (in the margins)

Comment: Hey @zazzyzeph did you find a solution? I'd be curious what you found, and if it works on Windows 10 Email App, as it doesn't support the usual VML code we used for background images in outlook.

Comment: Same I'm struggling too