# background image outlook reapetable

Tags: html, email, outlook, styles, vml

Hi I have strange issue with background image in `outlook`. I implemented background image for mail. Its working with some images, but the others (same format - `jpg`, same dimensions) are displayed as smaller then they are and are repeated to fill whole cell. Here is code:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
 <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" href="<%= url %>" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:648px;height:324px;">
 <v:fill type="tile" src="<%= ImageUrl%>" color="#becbd0" />
 <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
```

This is `asp.net` code so `<%= ImageUrl%>` is the proper image url.

**UPDATE**
What worked for me was change type="tile" to type="frame" in v:fill tag.

Comment: Have you checked out [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm/)? If you get stuck, her is [another method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook/13259519#13259519) for full-email backgrounds.

Comment: I've provided a good answer to this question here if you'd like to take a look:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13/23346010#23346010